# A Question on Linear Operators (one to one condition statement)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\to Y$ be linear operator.

I want to show that

$$
Tu = Tv \quad \text{for} \quad u,v \in Domain(T) \Rightarrow u=v 
$$
if and only if

$$
Tu=0 \Rightarrow u=0.
$$

I saw this in a functional analysis book without any explain. But I'm a newbie so I could not prove this statement. Help me please.

Comment: I can show one direction with $v=0$ but the other direction I could not prove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a tag `functional-analysis` for your question though, this is actually a general (very basic) fact in linear algebra (this could be the reason why you wouldn't see any explanation for the fact in a Functional Analysis textbook which assumes one knows basic linear algebra):

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ (or other field) and suppose $T:X\to Y$ is a linear mapping. Then $T$ is injective if and only if $\ker T=\{0\}$.

It is immediate from the *linearity* of the mapping $T$.

Note that for the proposition above, no norm structure is needed for $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$(\implies)$ Note that $Tu=0=T(0)$. So by the hypothesis, $u=0$.

$(\impliedby)$ $Tu=Tv$ implies $T(u-v)=0$, so that $u-v=0$. Then $u=v$.

Answer (score 0):

If $Tu=Tv\implies u=v$ then you have that

$$Tu=T0\underbrace{=}_{T\:\:\rm{linear}}0\implies u=0.$$

Conversely, if $Tu=0\implies u=0$ then one has

$$Tu=Tv\iff T(u-v)=0\implies u-v=0\implies u=v.$$

Answer (score 0):

The key for the other direction is that $T$ is *linear*, so $Tu=Tv$ if and only if $Tu-Tv=0$, i.e., $T(u-v)=0$. So if $Tw=0$ implies $w=0$ and $T(u-v)=0$...